# Does using a try-with-resource block for CloseableHttpClient also close the returning CloseableHttpResponse?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, try-with-resources

I'm trying to workout if a `try-with-resource` closes just the `CloseableHttpClient`, or also closes the response too.

For example,

```
private static CloseableHttpResponse sendRequest()
        throws IOException
{
    final HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest =
            buildRequest(url, requestMethod, requestParameters, httpHeaders);

    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build())
    {
        return client.execute(httpUriRequest);
    }
}
```

We all know this will close the `CloseableHttpClient` as expected. What about the result of that call though? `CloseableHttpClient` returns a `CloseableHttpResponse`. Does that also need to be closed, either in the invoking code, or somewhere else? Or is it closed at the same time as `CloseableHttpClient` with that `try-with-resource`?

Bonus question: How can I prove to myself that things are actually being closed? I'm looking at the thread pool in IntelliJ but can't quite workout where/when things are closing.

Comment: Why should the current method close a resource when it is being returned? It is callers responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by [Jhilton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9520479/jhilton) is perfectly correct (my +1). However, as far as HttpClient specific resource management is concerned closure of `HttpClient` instance results in closure of all kept alive and active connection, including those currently associated with `HttpResponse` instances. That essentially means one does not have to close `HttpResponse` instances if closing `HttpClient` instance used to execute the message exchange but such pattern is very much discouraged.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. I know how the try-with-resource works in general, but wanted to know what happens in my situation, so I'm as accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try-with-resource will close only the resources declared in the try clause

```
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build())
```

e.g It will only close the variable "client"

Also if the response were to be closed, It would become a problem to extract the data, so the responsibility of closing it should fall elsewhere.